# paypal API delay disbursement with variable amount of money

Tags: javascript, node.js, paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-adaptive-payments

I saw https://developer.paypal.com/docs/archive/adaptive-payments/ht-ap-basicChainedPayment-curl-etc/ and https://developer.paypal.com/docs/commerce-platform/payment/delayed-disbursement/ and https://developer.paypal.com/docs/commerce-platform/payment/checkout/ to try to process a payment after the user has made an order, but in my case, I need:

the user to approve upon a preset amount of money. Meaning, they will be on the website for a certain amount of time, and when they click the "end" button, the total amount needs to be calculated, and taken from them automatically, like uber, which automatically charges someone after the ride is over.

How can I get this functionality with the paypal API? It seems that I can only process an order once it has been approved with a set amount from the user, but how can I automatically take a variable amount from them?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a v2/orders payment with `intent: 'AUTHORIZE',`.  After the buyer approves the order, you do an API call to authorize it.  Later, when the time comes to do the disbursement for your (potentially lesser) variable amount, you do an API call to capture that amount.

Here are the three server-side API calls:

1. https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/orders/v2/#orders_create
2. https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/orders/v2/#orders_authorize
3. https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/orders/v2/#orders_capture

---

And, here is demo pattern of the client-side UI needed for the first two steps: https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/server

(In the second fetch() XHR, you'll be doing an authorize rather than proceeding straight to capture, since you want this intervening step. Your capture comes later.)

Comment: interesting, so does the user need to approve a much greater amount than wlll be taken? Meaning, say the website is $1 per minute, and I don't know how many minutes they will be on, so do I have to initially charge them for, say, $200, and thereby set a maximum for 200 minutes?

Comment: An authorization is not a charge, but yes, your eventual capture must be within a default tolerance of 115% of the initially authorized amount.

Comment: So is it then impossible to accomplish what uber does, meaning when someone orders a ride for uber, they don't need to authorize a $6000 charge, for example (if someone was driving accross country), it is charged after. Is this impossible to do with the paypal API?

Comment: That would require the PayPal business account be enabled for "Reference Transactions", to be able to create billing agreements. You could contact PayPal's business support via https://www.paypal.com/us/smarthelp/contact-us to explain the business need and request this Reference Transaction feature, which is only available to some businesses.